# Should I use (pbuh) when mentioning Muhammad?

Tags: discussion

I have gotten the impression that some people are offended by casual use of Muhammad's name. Even if I'm not offending someone, I wonder if using (pbuh) would encourage more people to be favorably disposed to read -- and especially, answer -- my questions. Is it a good idea to use (pbuh)? If it is a good idea, is there a good resource for learning how to use it properly?

**Edit**: I realize that SE is supposed to be a non-religious environment, but I also realize that islam.SE pushes this boundary, to put it mildly. I'm trying to fit into the culture so as to get more responses.

Comment: Related on meta: [Don't append “SAWW”, “PBUH”, “RA”, “AS” etc in front of names and titles if the original author hasn't and don't change it either](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1131/3487) and [All questions should show respect for Allah, Holy Prophet(PBUH) and sahaba's etc](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/36/3487). On main: [Salawāt upon prophets - for the reader, the writer, or both?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1985/3487).

Comment: Helpful, thank you. I'm always torn about whether to take a hard line about the SE culture, or to accept the fact that islam.SE attracts devoted Muslims who place their relationship with God above the rules of SE. Not to say it's only islam.SE; I see the same thing on christianity.SE. My main goal here is to get more answers. I'm trying everything I can think of. I get downvotes that are almost certainly due to causing offense, so maybe I'm being ignored for the same reason? Anyway, thanks for pointing me to that post.

Comment: Oh, I posted that comment before you added to yours.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Ok, I've read through those other posts. I guess mine is subtly different: I'm not asking about what is proper, but about how to encourage people to be favorably disposed to a question, thus more likely to answer it. Please let me know if you have further thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

> I have gotten the impression that some people are offended by casual use of Muhammad's name.

There's, almost, always going to be someone who will be offended. Do not worry about that. Instead, try to make your questions and answers objective, well-researched and well-formatted, and if that's taken care of your post is good shape. (And answers should actually answer the question).

> I wonder if using (pbuh) would encourage more people to be favorably disposed to read -- and especially, answer -- my questions. Is it a good idea to use (pbuh)?

It is your wish whether or not you use pbuh, saww, as, ra etc. And we rather have a user base who are indifferent to those salutations when it comes to reading and answering question, than those who are.

> Is there a good resource for learning how to use it properly?

Read some Islamic literature in English and you would understand how, when and where they are used.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the rulings of the SE model we shouldn't use neither (pbuh) nor (peace be upon him) nor (Prayers and Blessings of Allah be upon him) nor any kind of expressions like this.

Muslims tend to see calling him simply Muhammad as a kind of disrespect, which IMO and to stay somehow conform with the polices of SE would be using a kind of at least more respectful expression like the Prophet Muhammad or the Messenger of Allah etc. of course if the full expression is quoted in a source that wouldn't disagree with SE polices as far as I can tell. So that would be my midday solution or suggestion:
 Calling him Prophet Muhammad or Messenger of Allah and if in a quote take it as is in the source.

I'm not that long active here to say whether it would be easy or hard to make an end to the excessive using of these kinds of expressions of honor for the Prophets, Allah, Sahaba and other honorable people and also greetings like as-salamu alaikum (some also use abbreviations) and thanking like jazakaAllah khairan ... (you may find posts about all of that here on meta) which IMO take a lot of space and in our hearts we know that we would use them, and i don't think it is necessary to post them.
 Of course you could oppose my post and say hey you use it the same excessive way. My answer wouldn't be logical either: I see that most of the people do so and if we can find a consensus to make a cleaning action to remove all the unnecessary stuff I'd be the first to join it. And I'm lately really thinking about posting here a Question about this matter.

On the other hand I'm not sure whether this plays a role on the voting behavior: all I usually see we have seasonal activities, so out of Ramadan, Hajj, maybe 'Ashura' and other more or less short occasions the site has visits but rarely new posts (IMO even during that time most of the new posts are already covered to 80-90% so they maybe slightly special cases of answered questions), so only during that time there's a more reasonable voting behavior out of that you may find most of the answers accepted (if they were accepted at all) with 0 up-votes and most of the questions which include a sin in the title down-voted.
 Apparently nobody cares about the quality of a post rather than sin and sinner, and sects and sectarianism. But maybe and as said above I'm not long enough active to say that not quoting this expression of honor may play a role in the voting behavior. 
Sometimes I ask myself whether Muslims are even too lazy to click to vote here. I mean we really have many great questions but from around 2014 till now it would be hard to find a question or answer with a double-digit voting total which doesn't really reflect the quality of an answer or question, while in older posts you may find much more of these kinds, and I even found answers with many votes which miss a lot of what I would qualify as even a good answer (and I don't think I have high standards).